# Read CSV file selected at client side in C# through AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a requirement in which user will select a CSV file locally, I have to read the file contents and  dump them on a JQGrid. Yes, the browser is IE :)..What should I do in order to achieve this?

Comment: You can't read a file on the client side, so you'll need to upload it to the server than parse it as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it server side.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

(FileUploadControl.OpenFile)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do that with the all new HTML5 features, so if you are going for IE9+

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Check this out.

Basically, you need the FileReader component (`FileReader.readAsText(Blob|File, opt_encoding)`) and then just parse everything with regexps or whatever floats your goat.

If, you definetely need to do this in client side AND in older IE, maybe ActiveX is a solution:

[ActiveX' FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Then refer to Rory McCrossan comment, can't be done unless you use ActiveX, about which I'll extend the answer

Answer (score 0):

Barring that you are not capable of using HTML 5 (lower version of ie etc.):

Javascript can't access the file system directly, so you are going to have to use the file upload tag and parse it on the server: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-file-tag.htm

You can then use AJAX to query the contents and pull it back down into the grid.

Comment: You can read a file client side using FileReader, although support from IE is (unsuprisingly) lagging behind. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader

Comment: Provided that version of IE they are using actually supports it...... I have little faith in companies to have current browsers anymore.